# Jenkins, Gradle. connectedCheck fails without showing emulator window

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I'm using jenkins+gradle to build my android application. I run command

```
gradle clean connectedCheck build
```

And everything is ok when i checked box in jenkins settings 'Show emulator window', but when i remove it build fails.
*Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: No connected devices!*

But before gradle started in log was message
*[android] Emulator is ready for use (took 59 seconds)*

Can i build app without showing emulator window?
Problem is that my CI server doesn't have X server, so i think could be problems with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to remove property 'Show emulator window'. If server doesn't have X server you need to install **Xvnc Plugin** to Jenkins, and leave property checked